Bad value for type BigDecimal: NaN
In a databricks environment I've connected to an external postgres table and saved it as a DataFrame locally. When trying to save the DataFrame as a table in a catalog (CREATE TABLE), I get the following error:
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type BigDecimal : NaN

I've identified the column causing this problem, but it's not of type BigDecimal, but decimal. I've tried casting the data to string in the query and working with that, but that does not work. Has anyone encounted this and are there any suggested solutions? I'm working with pyspark in this case.

NaN means that you are dealing with Floats in some intermediate step - show us some code please, there must be some conversion you are unaware of.

Seems there is mismatch with DataBrick and decimals. In Postgres the decimal(numeric) type allows NaN, in DataBrick(Decimal(java.math.BigDecimal)) it does not. Seems you will either need to use float in DataBricks or clean the data in the Postgres table.

Turns out my last comment was wrong, thanks Adrian. In postgres, all numeric types contain the possibility of NaN, not just floats. They also work a bit differently than IEEE-float-nans when it comes to comparing them: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html

with this information, it seems like a bug in DataBricks or its underlying libraries to not support NaN in the database. Though I suppose cleaning your data is a more practical approach than going off to fix the java-ecosystem.
